# Can't figure out error 1064 in MySQL

Tags: mysql

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '$TABLE[] = "CREATE TABLE `perscom_admin_units` ( `primary_id_field` int(11) N' at line 1

Here is the query:

```
$TABLE[] = "CREATE TABLE `perscom_admin_units` (
  `primary_id_field` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` text,
  `mos` mediumtext,
  `image` text,
  `responsibilities` mediumtext,
  `prerequisites` mediumtext,
  `forum_usergroup` text,
  PRIMARY KEY(primary_id_field)
);";
```

Any idea whats going wrong?

Comment: From the message it looks like you're passing to MySQL the `'$TABLE[] = "` part too. This isn't SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Just write this (remove `$TABLE[]=`):

```
CREATE TABLE `perscom_admin_units` (
  `primary_id_field` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` text,
  `mos` mediumtext,
  `image` text,
  `responsibilities` mediumtext,
  `prerequisites` mediumtext,
  `forum_usergroup` text,
  PRIMARY KEY(primary_id_field)
);
```

`$TABLE` is a PHP variable, I tink you just want to run MySQL code.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are mysql lower  version. Can you test these code.

```
          $TABLE[] = "CREATE TABLE perscom_admin_units (  primary_id_field int NOT 
     NULL   auto_increment,  name text,  mos mediumtext,  image text,  responsibilities mediumtext, prerequisites mediumtext,  forum_usergroup text, 
PRIMARY KEY(primary_id_field) )";
```

First test these SQL in mysql yog after you can put these SQL in your code

```
CREATE TABLE perscom_admin_units (  primary_id_field int NOT 
     NULL   auto_increment,  name text,  mos mediumtext,  image text,  responsibilities mediumtext, prerequisites mediumtext,  forum_usergroup text, 
PRIMARY KEY(primary_id_field) );
```

Thank you.